# Airflow dynamic task dependency setting works only for last element on the list

Tags: dependencies, airflow

I have created an airflow job that checks files on a client server in Google Cloud Platform and then copies it to specified folder.
Everything worked smoothly until I decided to create dynamic tasks in airflow. Now my dependencies don't want to get set properly like this:
[image]

Instead, I ended up with this:
[image]

Here is the code that I created for this purpose (I included only relevant part):

```
EXPORT_BUCKET='gs://export'
SOURCE_BUCKET='gs://source'
system_list=["main"]
type_list=["road_cell_counters", "road_counters", "impact_counters", "cell_counters"]

...

with models.DAG(dag_id='return_feed',
        schedule_interval=None,
        description='return feed',
        default_args=default_dag_args) as dag: 

...
 
        for system in system_list:
            for type in type_list:
                feed_check = BashOperator(
                task_id=str(type)+'_check_'+str(system),
                project_id=project,
                xcom_push=True,
                bash_command='''gsutil -q stat {source_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/day={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="DAY") }}}}/_SUCCESS'''.format(source_bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, system=system, type=type),
                dag = dag
                )        
        
                feed_copy = BashOperator(
                task_id=str(type)+'_copy_'+str(system),
                project_id=project,
                bash_command='''gsutil cp -r {source_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/day={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="DAY") }}}} {export_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/'''.format(source_bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, export_bucket=EXPORT_BUCKET, system=system, type=type),
                dag = dag
                )


get_parameters >> feed_check >> feed_copy
```

So in my case I would like to go over first list and then over second to cover all possibilities of tasks. For that I created two for loops to go over all elements inside of the lists. 
As you can see, for some reason, only the last element on the list has correct dependency, why is that??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try moving the task dependency expressions inside the `for type in type_list:` loop.  Otherwise, the last instance of `feed_check` and `feed_copy` will be used when the dependencies are set outside of the loops.

```py
    for system in system_list:
            for type in type_list:
                feed_check = BashOperator(
                task_id=str(type)+'_check_'+str(system),
                project_id=project,
                bash_command='''gsutil -q stat {source_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/day={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="DAY") }}}}/_SUCCESS'''.format(source_bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, system=system, type=type),
                dag = dag
                )

                feed_copy = BashOperator(
                task_id=str(type)+'_copy_'+str(system),
                project_id=project,
                bash_command='''gsutil cp -r {source_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/day={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="DAY") }}}} {export_bucket}/system={system}/type={type}/year={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="YEAR") }}}}/month={{{{ ti.xcom_pull(key="MONTH") }}}}/'''.format(source_bucket=SOURCE_BUCKET, export_bucket=EXPORT_BUCKET, system=system, type=type),
                dag = dag
                )


                get_parameters >> feed_check >> feed_copy
```

[image]